# Using Typescript object in HTML

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript, and I would like to be able to run a method when I click on an element.
I've created a project and process ts file with awesome-typescript-loader with webpack.

I've created a TS class :

```
export class MyApp {

    myMethod(myParam: number): void {
        console.log("I'm here");
    }
}

export const myApp = new MyApp();
```

in my main.ts, I'm importing the ts file :

```
import { theApp } from "./ts/myApp";
```

and in my html I've :

```
<div onclick="theApp.myMethod(123);"></div>
```

but I can see the following error :

> uncaught ReferenceError: myApp is not defined at
>   HTMLDivElement.onclick

what is the correct way to use TS object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `theApp` onto the `window` object: `window["theApp"] = theApp;`

Then it is globally available and should be reachable by your `onclick` handler.

```js
class MyApp {
    myMethod(myParam) {
        console.log("I'm here");
    }
}
window['theApp'] = new MyApp();
```

```html
<div onclick="theApp.myMethod(123);">take theApp from window implicitly</div>
<div onclick="window['theApp'].myMethod(123);">take theApp from window explicitly</div>
```

Comment: if I do this, I've a tslint error : object access via string literals is disallowed. But anyway, if I cheat and do const indexer = "theApp";
window[indexer] = theApp;
I've an undefined error when i do onclick="window['theApp'].myMethod(123);" in the div

Comment: Then your code is not executed. Make sure it is loaded on the HTML page. See my snippet: it works.

Comment: Usually your linter setting is ok, because usually you try to avoid accessing the window object. Instead, consider using a framework that takes care of rendering your HTML (such as Angular or one of the many others you can choose from), use jQuery from within TypeScript classes/functions to add the click handler to your DOM or use even use jQuery or plain TypeScript to generate your DOM elements.

Comment: For writing Web apps I prefer TypeScript components that are applied onto an empty HTML page (just html, head and body), and generate the entire DOM themselves. For convenience, I make use of jQuery. If you work that way, your app will compile way faster than an Angular app, you have static type checking for all your code (static type checking does not work on Angular's HTML templates if you do not turn on AOT compilation), less magic und thus benefit from easier debugging. Consider using observables like the ones from RxJS in order to build a solid app.

Comment: seems that without exporting, it's working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update the following lines

MAIN.TS

Import statement

```
import { myApp } from "./ts/myApp";
```

Constructor

```
constructor(private theApp: myApp) {}
```

Function call in html file

```
<div onclick="theApp.myMethod(123);"></div>
```